# Is there a way to reinstall Linux and keep my partition table?

Tags: linux, partition, reinstall

This is my current partition table:

[image]

Which option should I use to reinstall Linux?  Does the erase disc option also erase the partitions? Would I need to create a new partition table? Or would choosing the something else option allow me to keep my current table and just erase the current data in those partitions?

I had a good partitioning tutorial from here, but sadly can't seem to find it. I should also mention that I don't need to keep anything. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is. Choose custom or extended partition manager not auto. Assign mount points to existing partitions and check delete (maybe not for /home if you want to keep your data).

Comment: Also, the swap partition is passé, as the performance issue with swap files was solved two years ago.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't need to keep anything.  I'll edit my question.